# Insert partial view into layout retrieved from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I am storing user-editable HTML layouts inside a database, but I would like to know if there's a way to render a partial view in the middle of some of that content.

For example:

```
<div>
This is the header 
@Html.Action("WebsiteTemplate", "Page")
</div>
```

I've thought that I could split the top & lower content into 2 separate columns, but is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: I may not be understanding the question but why couldn't you just use `@Html.Partial`?

Comment: The problem is that I'm mixing HTML content stored in a database and need to make a call to @Html.Partial in the middle of that HTML database content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to parse with Razor content which you retrieved from database. You may use [RazorEngine](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/) project for that purpose. It has some limitations (like, `@Raw()` instead of  `@Html.Raw()`), but cover many scenarios.

Comment: Very interesting - I'll check this out tomorrow.  Thanks!